# Linux iptables NAT

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, nat

So I need to setup a server that servers a NAT server for IPMI network

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx = external IP(internet IP)
aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa = internal IP A
bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb = internal IP B

User 1 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1112 <-> aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa
User 2 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1113 <-> bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx sits on a firewall server with a NIC on both networks to serve as the bridge between the two. Let me know anymore required info I cannot figure out how to do this with iptables.

This is what I have
`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE`
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --dport 1111 -j DNAT --to 10.1.0.8:80`

Comment: Sorry this is a linux box using iptables.

Comment: This is pretty basic, and there are many tutorials which explain this in depth. What have you done so far?

Comment: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE   
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d (eth0IP) --dport  1111 -j DNAT --to 10.1.0.8:80